# How to start data entry in RadWaterMarkTextBox at position 10

Tags: wpf, vb.net, telerik

I have a RadWatermarkTextBox where I'd like to start the data entry in position 10 instead of one (or zero).  I tried using Padding but it padded the watermark only.  See the image below for more clarification.  "Name" has the padding, "Address" does not.

I'd like the data entry for Name to start where the watermark begins.  However when actually entering data, it starts at position 1.

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to actually have the data entry start at position 10?

XAML:

```
<telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox x:Name="txtSoldToName" 
     Padding="10,0,0,0"
     Text="{Binding soldToName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
     MaxLength="60">
     <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox.WatermarkContent>
         <TextBlock Text="Limit to 60 characters or less" FontSize="12" Foreground="#969696" />
     </telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox.WatermarkContent>
</telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox>
```

Thanks.